# Generating t statistics from p values - binomial test multiple comparisons

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, t-distribution

I am using the binomial test to generate a series of p values. However, my method of multiple comparisons correction that I wish to apply to this series requires that I also have the corresponding t statistic for each p value. Typically in performing the student's t test, we use a lookup table to go *from* t statistics *to* p values. Does this go both ways? It seems like it should, but I am unsure. Thanks!

Edit: Another good answer would be to tell me a good way to correct for multiple comparisons in my scenario: i have a time series of p values generated from the binomial test at each point. I want a multiple comparisons correction technique that will select contiguous windows of time. I was going with the cluster permutation test (aka the excursion test), but maybe that's not appropriate?

Comment: It may be that a different multiple comparisons correction will be more appropriate for you. Can you say more about your situation, your data, your analyses, & your goals?

Comment: Why not ask about an appropriate multiple comparisons procedure rather than naively choose a procedure that may be unsuitable and then ask how to do something you hope will make it work?

Comment: Edited to address your comments.